# Método main sin error sin pasar argumentos pero con parámetro args

Tags: java

Me pregunto por qué no salta error al escribir el método `main` por defecto y ejecutarlo sin pasarle ningún argumento, aún con el `String[]args` como parámetro, ej:

```
package prueba;
class Prueba{
  public static void main(String[]args){
    System.out.print("Hola");
  }
}
```

Sin embargo, cualquier método de la api de Java que uses requiere que le pases los parámetros predeterminados o da error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los argumentos que se pasan a ese método se establecen en las propiedades del Proyecto, en el caso de que no le indiques ningún argumento se enviará un array de String vacío, esto lo realiza el IDE que utilices de forma interna.

En el caso de que quieras invocar al método main de esa clase desde otra clase, verás que si debes informar el parámetro obligatoriamente.

En el caso de que estés ejecutando la clase desde la consola de comandos, puedes especificar los argumentos despues del nombre de la clase: C> java Prueba argumento1 argumento2 argumento3 ...

Un saludo.